# GnuPG key details (RSA)

Tags: gnupg

Given a GnuPG RSA key, is it possible to get the corresponding parameters? I would like to "see" numbers composing the key: $N, e$ and potentially using a private one $p$ and $q$.

Comment: does the latex macro work here?

Answer (score 0):

After the second or third Google search session and reading manuals and forums I got the answer:

```
➜  /tmp  gpg --list-keys --with-key-data 0x08A63FFA
tru::1:1389032036:0:3:1:5
pub:-:2048:1:7A09556408A63FFA:2014-04-13:::-:Joe Tester (with stupid passphrase) <joe   at foo.bar>::escaESCA:
pkd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
➜  /tmp
```